androiddeployqt fails saying it couldn't 'load resources table' in android.jar
I want to learn how to compile QT apps for Android. So I setup all the relevant components in QT Creator. I have:
openJDK 21.0.3
SDK 13.0
NDK 25.1.8937393
OpenSSL

I created two emulators in the 'devices' tab, one for arm64-8a and one for x86_64. Finally I created a new project, and without making any changes, hit compile. But regardless of what platform and emulator I select I run into this same error:
> Task :desugarDebugFileDependencies

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
25 actionable tasks: 25 executed

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
   > Android resource linking failed
     aapt2 E 07-30 14:22:25  6509  6509 LoadedArsc.cpp:94] RES_TABLE_TYPE_TYPE entry offsets overlap actual entry data.
     aapt2 E 07-30 14:22:25  6509  6509 ApkAssets.cpp:149] Failed to load resources table in APK '/home/isaac/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-35/android.jar'.
     error: failed to load include path /home/isaac/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-35/android.jar.

What does this mean and how can I go about fixing it?

Not familiar with QT but from Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0. you appear to be a using a newer version of Gradle than what Android uses: https://developer.android.com/build/releases/gradle-plugin As Android uses specialized Gradle plugins in its build system you should review how QT is invoking.

Came across a solution here https://planet.kde.org/hanyangzhang-2024-07-23-building-and-running-qml-android-applications/.
Basically, the Android Gradle Plugin is outdated and incompatible with android-35. Here's how to solve this: In your project folder, navigate to build/<name-of-configuration>/android-build and open build.gradle. In the dependencies block change the line:
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1'

to indicate a newer version of the plugin - the post I linked to suggests:
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.4.1'

If you leave it like this Qt will complain that the Gradle version is too old for this plugin version. So we need to update Gradle too. In the same directory, continue to navigate through gradle/wrapper and find the file gradle-wrapper.properties. In here, change
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.3-bin.zip

to
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.6-bin.zip

Now, for some reason, my Qt still complained about a namespace thing. So back in the android-build folder return to build.gradle. Open the file and somewhere in the android section add a line like this:
namespace="org.qtproject.<name of your project>"

Now everything should compile just fine and we can all live happily ever after!
